# Cases of quasi-coincident "almost orthogonal" projections of n-dimenstional polytopes in (n-k)-spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

Background:

In Regular Polytopes, Coxeter shows that the familiar 3-dimensional rhombic dodecahedron resulting from a true orthogonal projection of the 4-cube has a "floor-plan" which is the same as the "floor-plan" of a different less familiar dodecahedron resulting from an "almost-orthogonal" projection of a 5-cube.  (The latter projection is "almost-orthogonal" because Coxeter introduces a very slight bit of perspective into it.)

Question:

Are there any other known cases of such "quasi-coincident" shadows in n-space of two objects in (n+1)-space and (n+2)-space.

I am particularly interested in any known cases involving shadows in 9-space of objects in 10-space and 11-space - in this regard, see also this question:

[Are the roots of E6 in 9-space ever treated as an orthogonal projection of a set of points in 11-space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546034/are-the-roots-of-e6-in-9-space-ever-treated-as-an-orthogonal-projection-of-a-set)

Thanks as always for whatever time you can afford to spend considering this question.